# setInterval (play-pause) mouseenter

Tags: jquery, html, setinterval

I'm trying to set controlled by a mouseenter mouseleave-but setInterval not working properly. The code is written like this:

```
  var cont = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){cont++; console.log(cont);}, 4500);  
  $(".thumbSlider").on({
      mouseenter: function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        console.log("se para en "+cont);
      },
      mouseleave: function() {
        if (timer == null) {
          var timer = setInterval(function(){cont++; console.log("se reanuda"+cont);}, 4500);      
        };
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a new variable in the mouseleave function, it's not the same variable.

Drop the `var` statement

```
mouseleave: function() {
    if (timer == null) {
      timer = setInterval(function(){
                  cont++; 
                  console.log("se reanuda"+cont);
              }, 4500);      
    };
}
```